# Using google authentication and google group in my code

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, openid

I want to use google authentication to authenticate a user, and then hopefully using a Google API to see if that user is a member of a certain group. If yes, my program runs, otherwise the program will let the user take some actions. I as the manager of the google group I can manually add/remove users from google site.

I read and understand the OAuth part. So I know I can authorize a user without any problems. The problem is confirming group membership.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3757793/1467115

Comment: That question/answer has been deleted, what was it?

Comment: It's on archive.org http://web.archive.org/web/20150701084305/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757793/api-for-google-groups

Comment: Also see: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40367/is-it-possible-to-allow-only-certain-accounts-from-a-specific-group-in-google-ap